# Dataview Webpart > Sort limited to displayed items

Tags: sharepoint, sorting, pagination, dataviewwebpart

sorting in dataviewwebpart only sorting within display items. Paging is enabled to display 10 items per page. Also, How do I put 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, (next, previous) for the paging?

They give you dataview wp but looks like it's also limited. I wish it had more capabilities like gridview. Anyone????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this issue.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campaign Members">
<ItemTemplate> 
<%# RemoveCharacters(Eval("CampaignMembers").ToString())%> 
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C# code:

```
// Make sure declare using System.Text.RegularExpression; 
protected string RemoveCharacters(object String) 
{ 
    string s1 = String.ToString(); 
    string newString = Regex.Replace(s1, @"#[\d-];", string.Empty); 
    newString = Regex.Replace(newString, "#", " "); 
    return newString.ToString(); 
}
```